# bootstrap input-group addon styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's `input-group` on a textarea, what I want is to have the label, or `input-group-addon` above the `textarea`, but due to the styling of the 'addon' element it doesn't look very good (especially on the right side).

How can I make the `textarea` look decent, using `input-group`?

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PNaQzePZQ94Q4ySPzNL5?p=preview) to see difference on `<input>` and `<textarea>`

I guess what I'd like is slightly rounded edges on the right side, like the one on the left, on the `textarea` input, the normal input is fine.

Comment: be more clear . what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override the regular add-on by adding a new class to the `textarea` and apply some `css` changes on it:

```
<div class="input-group-addon textarea-addon"> Description </div>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
```

and for the css:

```
.textarea-addon{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
  border:1px solid #ccc !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
textarea{
  border-top-left-radius:0px !important;
  border-top-right-radius:0px !important;
}
```

If your'e using less or compass I'd use variables instead of plain numbers.
In addition, you should add some browser compatibility properties (such as -webkit and -moz prefixes)

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/dMa4UPLMqOXdVITzFKNr?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

How about this:-

```css
.row .form-group .input-group-addon {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.row .form-group textarea.form-control {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row" style="padding:30px 100px;">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">Description</div>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the default style for this element is not expected to have the right not rounded corners when placed before the input field and has rounded corners to the left when it is placed after the left field .. you can add them this way or create a class with these features Included and add the Element

The input-group- addon default style don

```
<span class="input-group-addon" 
    style=" border-top-right-radius: 6px;   
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; border-right: solid 1px #ccc;">
  Description</span>
```

use span and not div for addon